# Customized Nullable struct

Tags: c#, clr

I am reading the [CLR Via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454)  book and trying out the example provided.

```
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyNullable<T> where T : struct
{
    private readonly  bool _hasValue ; //Should be false
    private readonly T _value; //Really should be value=default(T)

    public MyNullable(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
        _hasValue = true;
    }

    public bool HasValue {
        get { return _hasValue; }
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_hasValue)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Nullable object must have a value");
            }
            return _value;
        }
    }

    public T GetValueOrDefault()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    public T GetValueOrDefault(T defaultValue)
    {
        return !_hasValue ? defaultValue : _value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!_hasValue) return obj == null;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        return _value.Equals(obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return !_hasValue ? 0 : _value.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _hasValue ? _value.ToString() : "";
    }


    public static implicit operator MyNullable<T>(T value)
    {
        return new MyNullable<T>(value);
    }

    public static explicit operator T(MyNullable<T> value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }
}
```

This code is supposed to let me assign a null value to MyNullable as

MyNullable i = null;

but Visual Studio is giving me error message as 
"Cannot convert source type null to target type MyNullable"

I thought 
       **public static implicit operator MyNullable(T value)**
and

```
   **public static explicit operator T(MyNullable<T> value)**
```

Did the trick but seemed it's not the case.

Is there any way to make this code work?

Thanks.

Comment: Two come to mind.  There is this problem; there is no way for you to define an implicit conversion from either `T` or `null` but not anything else to `MyNullable`, and you also can't handle boxing the way `Nullable` can without compiler support.  To solve this problem you could have an implicit conversion from `object`, but then someone could put in a `string` or something and it would break; that would be bad.

Answer (score 1):

As @EricLippert stated in one of his recent blog posts, it is not possible to implement in user code. There are quite a few things happening behind the scenes.

See: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/

Comment: leppie is absolutely right here. There is plenty of compiler magic around the real `Nullable<T>` type and one of those magics is the ability to assign null literals to variables of nullable value type. There are no tricks you can pull to make the null literal convertible to something else.